# Checkbox control in a grid is not triggering fieldupdated event

Tags: acumatica

I have a selected checkbox on a custom grid is not triggering the Fieldupdated event.

```
    protected void MyTable_Selected_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e, PXFieldUpdated del)
{
    del?.Invoke(cache, e);
    var row = (MyTable)e.Row;
    if(row.Selected == true )
    {
        //
    }
}
```

The following is the code in aspx page

```
 <px:PXCheckBox ID="edSelected" runat="server" AlreadyLocalized="False" CommitChanges="True" DataField="Selected" Text="Selected">
                    </px:PXCheckBox>
```

DAC definition for the field

```
#region Selected
        public abstract class selected : IBqlField { }

        /// <summary>
        /// Used for selection on screens.
        /// </summary>
        [PXDBBool]
        //[PXDefault(false)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Selected")]
        public virtual bool? Selected { get; set; }
        #endregion
```

When i click in the grid there is a red mark appears and the value is not committed on server side.

[image]

Comment: I think you will have a hard time getting an event triggered from a Selected column. When the column is not named Selected it will behave like expected.

Comment: I have tried and still I am having the same issue

Comment: Hello, is it your custom screen or default Acumatica screen, if Acumatica screen, can you please share screen id.

Comment: @Muralidharan Ramakrishnan That was my point, checkbox column named 'Selected' seems to have a special behavior that prevents firing events. Reading the 'Selected' value in BLC graph also yield to reading wrong values. I think this is hardcoded by design because when I change the name from 'Selected' to something else than it works as expected.

Comment: Shot in the dark but have you tried setting AllowCheckAll="True" instead of the text "Selected such as shown? <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Selected" TextAlign="Center" Type="CheckBox" AllowCheckAll="True" AllowSort="False" AllowMove="False" Width="30px" ></px:PXGridColumn>

Comment: Same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52669383/unable-to-fire-the-fieldupdated-or-rowupdated-event-on-gl404000-screen

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I figured out the property "BatchUpdate" was set to "true" on the Grid, which prevents the changes to be commited to the server.

Once I set it to false it works fine :

[image]

Comment: That might break batch processing feature, use with caution.