# unable to fire the fieldupdated or rowupdated event on GL404000 screen

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to extend the AccountByPeriodEnq business logic, yet i'm facing the following problem :

I can't seem to fire the GLTranR_RowUpdated or GLTranR_Selected_FieldUpdated events. (Unless I click the refresh button, then the events are fired)

Here's my code :

```
  #region EventHandler
        protected void GLTranR_Selected_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e, PXFieldUpdated del)
        {
            del?.Invoke(cache, e);
            var row = (GLTranR)e.Row;
        }

        protected void GLTranR_RowUpdated(PXCache cache, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            var row = (GLTranR)e.Row;
        }

        #endregion
```

When I put a breakpoint on any of those methods, it never actually break.

It seems the original event is never fired as well (Located in AccountByPeriodEnq.cs graph) since I never see the Reclassify button being disabled.

```
protected virtual void GLTranR_Selected_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            reclassify.SetEnabled(GetSelectedTrans().Any());
        }
```

I have checked in the aspx and the commitchanges=true is set for the "Selected" field.

Here's the aspx :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/FormDetail.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
  ValidateRequest="false" CodeFile="GL404000.aspx.cs" Inherits="Page_GL404000"
  Title="Untitled Page" %>

<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPages/FormDetail.master" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="phDS" runat="Server">
  <px:PXDataSource ID="ds" runat="server" Visible="True" Width="100%" TypeName="PX.Objects.GL.AccountByPeriodEnq"
    PrimaryView="Filter" PageLoadBehavior="PopulateSavedValues">
    <CallbackCommands>
      <px:PXDSCallbackCommand CommitChanges="True" Name="previousperiod" HideText="True"/>
      <px:PXDSCallbackCommand CommitChanges="True" Name="nextperiod" HideText="True"/>
      <px:PXDSCallbackCommand DependOnGrid="grid" Name="Reclassify" CommitChanges="True"/>
      <px:PXDSCallbackCommand DependOnGrid="grid" Name="ReclassifyAll"/>
      <px:PXDSCallbackCommand DependOnGrid="grid" Name="ReclassificationHistory" StateColumn="IncludedInReclassHistory"/>
    </CallbackCommands>
  </px:PXDataSource>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="phF" runat="Server">
  <px:PXFormView ID="form" runat="server"   Width="100%"
    Caption="Selection" DataMember="Filter" DefaultControlID="edFinPeriodID" DataSourceID="ds" TabIndex="100">
    <Template>
      <px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" StartColumn="True" LabelsWidth="SM" ControlSize="M" ></px:PXLayoutRule>
      <px:PXSelector CommitChanges="True" ID="edOrganizationID" runat="server" DataField="OrganizationID"></px:PXSelector>
      <px:PXSegmentMask CommitChanges="True" ID="edBranchID" runat="server" DataField="BranchID" Autorefresh="true"></px:PXSegmentMask>
      <px:PXSelector CommitChanges="True" ID="edLedgerID" runat="server" DataField="LedgerID" Autorefresh="true"></px:PXSelector>
      <px:PXSelector CommitChanges="True" ID="edStartPeriodID" runat="server" DataField="StartPeriodID"></px:PXSelector>
      <px:PXSelector CommitChanges="True" ID="edEndPeriodID" runat="server" DataField="EndPeriodID" Autorefresh="True"></px:PXSelector>
      <px:PXSegmentMask CommitChanges="True" ID="edAccountID" runat="server" DataField="AccountID"></px:PXSegmentMask>
      <px:PXSegmentMask CommitChanges="True" ID="edSubID" runat="server" DataField="SubID" SelectMode="Segment"  ></px:PXSegmentMask>
      <px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" StartColumn="True" LabelsWidth="SM" ControlSize="S" ></px:PXLayoutRule>
      <px:PXDateTimeEdit CommitChanges="True" ID="edStartDateUI" runat="server" DataField="StartDateUI" ></px:PXDateTimeEdit>
      <px:PXDateTimeEdit CommitChanges="True" ID="edPeriodStartDate" runat="server" DataField="PeriodStartDateUI" ></px:PXDateTimeEdit>
      <px:PXDateTimeEdit CommitChanges="True" ID="edEndDateUI" runat="server" DataField="EndDateUI" ></px:PXDateTimeEdit>
      <px:PXDateTimeEdit CommitChanges="True" ID="edPeriodEndDateUI" runat="server" DataField="PeriodEndDateUI" ></px:PXDateTimeEdit>
      <px:PXNumberEdit runat="server" ID="CstPXNumberEdit1" DataField="UsrCreditTotal" CommitChanges="True" />
      <px:PXNumberEdit runat="server" ID="CstPXNumberEdit2" DataField="UsrDebitTotal" CommitChanges="True" />
      <px:PXNumberEdit runat="server" ID="CstPXNumberEdit14" DataField="UsrSolde" CommitChanges="True" />
      <px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" StartColumn="True" SuppressLabel="True" ></px:PXLayoutRule>
      <px:PXCheckBox CommitChanges="True" ID="chkShowSummary" runat="server" DataField="ShowSummary" ></px:PXCheckBox>
      <px:PXCheckBox CommitChanges="True" ID="chkIncludeUnposted" runat="server" DataField="IncludeUnposted" ></px:PXCheckBox>
      <px:PXCheckBox CommitChanges="True" ID="chkIncludeUnreleased" runat="server" DataField="IncludeUnreleased" ></px:PXCheckBox>
      <px:PXCheckBox CommitChanges="True" ID="chkIncludeReclassified" runat="server" DataField="IncludeReclassified" ></px:PXCheckBox>
      <px:PXCheckBox CommitChanges="True" ID="chkShowCuryDetail" runat="server" DataField="ShowCuryDetail" ></px:PXCheckBox>

      <px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" StartColumn="True">
      </px:PXLayoutRule>
      <px:PXNumberEdit ID="edBegBal" runat="server" DataField="BegBal">
      </px:PXNumberEdit>
      <px:PXNumberEdit ID="edTurnOver" runat="server" DataField="TurnOver">
      </px:PXNumberEdit>
      <px:PXNumberEdit ID="edEndBal" runat="server" DataField="EndBal">
      </px:PXNumberEdit>
      <px:PXGroupBox runat="server" ID="groupAffichage" Caption="Afficher" CommitChanges="True" DataField="UsrAffichage" RenderSimple="True" RenderStyle="RoundBorder">
        <ContentLayout Layout="Stack" />
        <Template>
          <px:PXRadioButton runat="server" ID="CstRadioButton15" Text="Tous" Value="0" Checked="False" GroupName="groupAffichage" />
          <px:PXRadioButton runat="server" ID="CstRadioButton16" Value="1" Text="Lettres" GroupName="groupAffichage" Checked="False" />
          <px:PXRadioButton runat="server" ID="CstRadioButton17" GroupName="groupAffichage" Value="2" Text="Non lettres" Checked="True" /></Template></px:PXGroupBox></Template>
  </px:PXFormView></asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="phG" runat="Server">
  <px:PXGrid ID="grid" runat="server"  Height="150px" 
    Width="100%" AllowPaging="True" AdjustPageSize="Auto" Caption="Summary By Period" SyncPosition ="True" FastFilterFields="TranDesc,RefNbr,"
    BatchUpdate="True" AllowSearch="True" SkinID="PrimaryInquire" RestrictFields="True" DataSourceID="ds" TabIndex="100" PreserveSortsAndFilters="False">
    <CallbackCommands>
      <Refresh RepaintControlsIDs="form"/>
    </CallbackCommands>
    <AutoSize Container="Window" Enabled="True" />
    <Mode AllowAddNew="False" AllowDelete="False"  />
    <Levels>
      <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="GLTranEnq">
        <Columns>
          <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Selected" TextAlign="Center" Type="CheckBox" Width="30px" AllowCheckAll="True" AllowShowHide="Server" CommitChanges="True"></px:PXGridColumn>
          <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Module" Width="100px" ></px:PXGridColumn>
          <px:PXGridColumn DataField="BatchNbr" Width="100px" LinkCommand="ViewBatch" ></px:PXGridColumn>
          <px:PXGridColumn DataField="TranDate" Width="100px" ></px:PXGridColumn>
          <px:PXGridColumn DataField="FinPeriodID" Width="100px" ></px:PXGridColumn>
          <px:PXGridColumn DataField="TranDesc" Width="224px" ></px:PXGridColumn>
          <px:PXGridColumn DataField="RefNbr" Width="100px" LinkCommand="ViewDocument" ></px:PXGridColumn>
          <px:PXGridColumn DataField="LineNbr" TextAlign="Right" Width="100px"  ></px:PXGridColumn>
          <px:PXGridColumn DataField="BranchID" Width="100px" ></px:PXGridColumn>
          <px:PXGridColumn DataField="AccountID" Width="108px" ></px:PXGridColumn>
          <px:PXGridColumn DataField="SubID" Width="198px" ></px:PXGridColumn>
          <px:PXGridColumn DataField="SignBegBalance" TextAlign="Right" Width="100px" ></px:PXGridColumn>
          <px:PXGridColumn DataField="DebitAmt" TextAlign="Right" Width="100px" ></px:PXGridColumn>
          <px:PXGridColumn DataField="CreditAmt" TextAlign="Right" Width="100px" ></px:PXGridColumn>
          <px:PXGridColumn DataField="SignEndBalance" TextAlign="Right" MatrixMode="True" Width="100px" ></px:PXGridColumn>
          <px:PXGridColumn DataField="CuryID"  AllowShowHide="Server" ></px:PXGridColumn>
          <px:PXGridColumn DataField="SignCuryBegBalance" TextAlign="Right" Width="100px" AllowShowHide="Server" ></px:PXGridColumn>
          <px:PXGridColumn DataField="CuryDebitAmt" TextAlign="Right" Width="100px" AllowShowHide="Server" ></px:PXGridColumn>
          <px:PXGridColumn DataField="CuryCreditAmt" TextAlign="Right" Width="100px" AllowShowHide="Server" ></px:PXGridColumn>
          <px:PXGridColumn DataField="SignCuryEndBalance" TextAlign="Right" Width="100px" AllowShowHide="Server" ></px:PXGridColumn>
          <px:PXGridColumn DataField="InventoryID" Width="120px" ></px:PXGridColumn>
          <px:PXGridColumn DataField="ReferenceID" Width="120px" ></px:PXGridColumn>
          <px:PXGridColumn DataField="ReferenceID_BaccountR_AcctName" Width="200px" ></px:PXGridColumn>
          <px:PXGridColumn DataField="ReclassBatchNbr" TextAlign="Right" Width="120px" AllowShowHide="Server" LinkCommand="ViewReclassBatch" ></px:PXGridColumn>
          <px:PXGridColumn DataField="IncludedInReclassHistory" AllowShowHide="False" Visible="false" SyncVisible="false" ></px:PXGridColumn>
          <px:PXGridColumn DataField="UsrLettrageNbr" Width="70" CommitChanges="True" /></Columns>
      </px:PXGridLevel>
    </Levels>
    <AutoSize Container="Window" Enabled="True" MinHeight="400" />
    <ActionBar DefaultAction="DoubleClick" />
  </px:PXGrid>
</asp:Content>
```

What am I missing ? I spent a few hours on it already and I've ran out of ideas.

Edit:

My end goal is to calculate the sum of the credit and debit for the selected lines on filter view. If you have any workaround to update these values everytime I select a new line, i'll take it.

Maybe with some javascript and a callback command ?

---

I opened a support ticket on this matter on the acumatica partner center.

Edit 2 :

So, I created my own custom selector :

```
#region UsrletSel
        [PXBool]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Lettrer")]

        public virtual bool? UsrletSel { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrletSel : IBqlField { }
        #endregion
```

Then I hid the base selector in aspx, and to keep the original logic I bound the new selector to the base one :

```
protected void GLTranR_UsrletSel_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row == null) return;
            var row = (GLTranR)e.Row;
            if(row.GetExtension<GLTranExt>().UsrletSel == true)
            {
                row.Selected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                row.Selected = false;
            }
        }
```

I set the property CommitChanges=True in aspx for my new field, but i'm still unable to fire any event on this screen.

do you have any idea ?

Edit 3 :

So I totaly randomly got my checkbox (but also the original selected checkbox) to trigger events. You have to double click on the checkbox. (Which doesnt make any sens.) But I can't really tell my customer "start by double clicking if you want your total to calculates".

At 20s 
http://recordit.co/1fzW3eDIO9

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final answer was the property "BatchUpdate" was set to "true" on the Grid, which prevents the changes to be commited to the server.

Once you set it to false it works fine :

[image]

Comment: That might break batch processing feature, use with caution.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there's no way to do it.

This is the same issue here:
[Checkbox control in a grid is not triggering fieldupdated event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52609314/checkbox-control-in-a-grid-is-not-triggering-fieldupdated-event)

The **Selected** field appears to have special hardcoded logic tied to it. When you read the Selected value in the BLC graph it doesn't provide the current value displayed on screen. Also the field doesn't fire events like the other fields.

I found only two way to get around this:

1. Use a field with a different name, if the field name is **Selected** it won't behave like other fields.
2. Try to implement all your logic using only DAC Field Attributes. This is very hard to achieve.

---

I don't have a complete solution for #2 but if all you need is a total this code would be a good start:

```
// Selected count
[PXUnboundFormula(typeof(Switch<Case<Where<DAC.selected, Equal<True>>, int1>, int0>), 
                    typeof(SumCalc<FilterDAC.selectedCount>))]
protected void DAC_Selected_CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
{
}

[PXProcessButton]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Select All")]
protected virtual void selectAll()
{
    foreach (DAC doc in Dataview.Select())
    {
        if (doc.Selected != true)
        {
            doc.Selected = true;
            Dataview.Cache.SetStatus(doc, PXEntryStatus.Updated);
        }
    }

    FilterDAC copy = PXCache<FilterDAC>.CreateCopy(FilterDAC.Current);
    PXFormulaAttribute.CalcAggregate<DAC.selected>(Dataview.Cache, copy);
    Filter.Update(copy);
}
```

Comment: Oh, strange that SO didnt point me this question suggestion. Thanks for your answer, yet it surprises me since even the native code tries to update the reclassify button state on Selected_fieldupdated event.

If I want to keep using a single checkbox on this screen to do all the processing, do you think I can : Hide the selected checkbox, show my own selectedCust checkbox, replicate the state of my own selectedCust checkbox on the selected base checkbox ? Also my goal is just to sum amounts of the selected lines and print it on the filter view, any workaround you could have in mind ?

Comment: Honestly dropping the Selected column and replacing it by something else is what I would do. I did achieve to sum the Selected column a long time ago using Attributes and a lot of strange workaround to get it to refresh properly but it was very difficult and I don't have that code on hand now.

Comment: I did found some of the code I used to get a Selected field Sum using attributes, I added it to my answer, maybe that could help if you choose to go that way. The difficulty here is that it's required to force update and refresh of the DAC because Selected field doesn't do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this code sample, but can you comment it a bit i'm struggling to see the purpose of the PXUnboundformula on the Selected column

Comment: Hello, I used a field not names selected, yet it still doesnt trigger any event :(